# Database view to impose corrections

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there an easy way in SQL (SQL Server) to take a table of raw (read-only) data and impose "corrections" on it, where the corrections would come from a separate table, and the output of corrected data set would be shown in a separate view?

For example, say this is the table of original data (where "Pineapples" is an error):

[image]

And this is the table of corrections (in this case, just one correction):

[image]

And the desired view would result in the following corrected data set being served up:

[image]

Any pointers for how to write a query or procedure to get this kind of corrected data?  I have a feeling it's obvious (like a join with a tweak), but really appreciate any pointers.  Been thinking for a while and haven't cracked this yet.

Comment: What if there are multiple rows in the corrected data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `coalesce` with an `outer join`:

```
select o.pk_id, o.col1, coalesce(c.col2, o.col2) newcol2
from original o
    left join corrected c on o.pk_id = c.fk_id
```

`coalesce` returns the first non-null value it finds, and the `outer join` says take everything from the `original` table and include any matching records from the `corrected` table.  So when there is a match, `c.col2` won't be `null` and will be returned.  Otherwise, `c.col2` will be `null` and `o.col2` will be returned.

Comment: Wow learned something completely new!  Never heard of coalesce().  Since there are a lot of columns that could be corrected, I just wanted to check if there's any elegant way to wrap all of that up, or if I just need to explicitly write out coalesce statements for each column?

Comment: @EmilyBeth Unfortunately I don't think there is a way to wrap it up any cleaner, you'd have to explicitly define it for each column.  With that said, `colaesce` can take multiple columns and return the first non-null one.  So you could write `coalesce(col1, col2, col3)` for example.  Glad it helped you out though!